# Make pointer point at the end of the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing

How to check if pointer is at the end of my array ?
This is the code I have. If `d` is entered and the pointer is at the end, don't do anything; if not, move to the right.

```
if(d == 'd') 
{
    if (*p != a[6])   //a[6] is the array length // this is where i need help
    {
        ++*p;
        num_mov++;
        print_status(a, *p, num_mov);
    }
    else
        print_status(a, *p, num_mov);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use condition

```
if ( p != a + 6)
```

Take into account that this statement

```
++*p;
```

does not increase the pointer itself. It increases the object pointed to by the pointer.

If you want to increase the pointer itself you should write

```
++p;
```

Also check whether the second parameter of the function `print_status` is declared as pointer. If so then you have to write

```
print_status(a, p, num_mov);
```

insetad of

```
print_status(a, *p, num_mov);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use p != a+6 instead to compare the pointers as this give a better answer if there are repeated elements in the array.

This will point past the end. For the last element use p!=(a+5)

Comment: Thank you that did the job.

Comment: If i want to set the pointer to point at the end of the array ?